# Selenium not able to locate element that actually exists

Tags: python, selenium

I am automating a boring data entry task, so I created a program that basically clicks and types for me using selenium. It runs great! except for when it reaches this specific "Edit Details..." element that I need clicked, however, selenium is unable to locate the element regardless of whatever method I try.

I've tried using a CSS selector that tried to access the ID to no avail. I also tried using XPATH, as well as trying to be more specific by giving it a 'contains' statement with the button text. As last resort, I used the selenium IDE to see what locator it registers when I physically click the button and it used the exact same ID that I state in my code. I am completely lost on how to go about fixing this.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import *

import pyautogui as py
import time, sys, os, traceback


#Launching Browser
browser = webdriver.Ie()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 15) #Waiting


#Laziness Functions
def clickCheck(Method, Locator, elemName):
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((Method, Locator)))
    print(elemName + ' Clickable')




#Commence main function
try:

    #Do alot of Clicks and Stuff until it reaches "Edit Details..." element

    """THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES"""
    time.sleep(3)
    clickCheck(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td[id="DSCEditObjectSummary"]', "Edit Details")
    elemEdit = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('td[id="DSCEditObjectSummary"]')
    elemEdit.click()




#FAILSAFES

except:
    print('Unknown error has Occured')
    exc_info = sys.exc_info()
    traceback.print_exception(*exc_info)
    del exc_info

finally: #Executes at the end and closes all processes
    print('Ending Program')
    browser.quit()
    os.system("taskkill /f /im IEDriverServer.exe")
    sys.exit()
```

```py
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with css selector == [id="DSCEditObjectSummary"]
```

This is what I get as an error, all I want is for the element to be clicked just like all other elements are being located by CSS_Selectors. The image below indicates in blue the exact line for the "Edit Details..." button.

[Edit Details Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFpAo.png)

Comment: it could be that the element you are trying to click is located in an iframe, therefore you need first driver.switch_to.frame() and then click the element, if this is the case. Also it could be that you don't need to specify 'td[id="etc"]' but only ...css_selector("DSCEditObjectSummary")

Comment: @PeterBejan I used [link](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors) , as a reference in formatting my css_selectors, and so far I've been specifying them with their attributes such as id, class etc and its been working great. I did, however try what you mentioned out of curiosity and I was thrown the same element not found error. For the iframe comment, you were right! it is being loaded into an iframe, I am not sure how to convert this to id the element?

Comment: you have to switch to iframe using. `driver.switch_to.frame('frame locator goes here")`. Then

Comment: * Then interact with the elements in iframe as usual. Switch back to parent window using `driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the locator. Please replace `elemEdit = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('td[id="DSCEditObjectSummary"]')` with `elemEdit = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('//td[@id="DSCEditObjectSummary"]')`

Comment: @PRERNAPAL I tried that as well already, but I think I figured out the solution. I did some digging to find that the frame that holds the element is nested in two other frames, which I think is causing the issue. If this is fixed I will post a solution for everyone else haha

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue may be with the page loading slowly, or as another commenter mentioned it's in an iFrame, etc. I typically try clicking by using X/Y coordinates with a macro tool like AppRobotic if you're running this on Windows. If it's an issue with the page loading slowly, I usually try stopping the page load, and interacting with the page a bit, something like this should work for you:

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch
x = win32com.client.Dispatch("AppRobotic.API")
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import *

import pyautogui as py
import time, sys, os, traceback

#Launching Browser
browser = webdriver.Ie()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 15) #Waiting


#Laziness Functions
def clickCheck(Method, Locator, elemName):
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((Method, Locator)))
    print(elemName + ' Clickable')

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
# wait 20 seconds
x.Wait(20000)
# scroll down a couple of times in case page javascript is waiting for user interaction
x.Type("{DOWN}")
x.Wait(2000)
x.Type("{DOWN}")
x.Wait(2000)
# forcefully stop pageload at this point
driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
# if clicking with Selenium still does not work here, use screen coordinates
x.MoveCursor(xCoord, yCoord)
x.MouseLeftClick
x.Wait(2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer more so for other folks who might be running into the same problem and stumble upon this post. As @PeterBejan mentioned, the element I was trying to click was nested in an iframe. I tried accessing the iframe except I was thrown a NoSuchFrameException. Further digging revealed that this frame was nested inside 3 other frames and I had to switch to each frame from top level down, to access the element. This was the code I used

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("TopLevelFrameName"))
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("SecondaryFrameName"))
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("TertiaryFrameName"))
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("FinalFrameName"))
clickCheck(By.ID, 'ElementID', "Edit Details")
elemEdit = browser.find_element_by_id("ElementID")
elemEdit.click()
```